# Javascript Count Down - Controlled by server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer

My script has a countdown timer, but has to be controlled by the server since the time can change at any time.

Usually counts down from 1 hour, but as it gets closer to 0, a user fired event from PHP will reset the time on MySQL database and the timer will shoot back to what ever time.

```
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#timer').load('api/getdata.php?clock=1');
    }, 600);
```

As you can see, currently the countdown is returned by a PHP script, which is called every 600ms (1000ms sometimes appears to skip a second).

I need to have a simple text countdown (Minutes and seconds), which synchronizes with the PHP script. But as it gets less than 30 seconds, would need to sync every second.

Is this possible with JS?

This is the code for the PHP

```
$from = time();
$to = strtotime($row['clock']);

$Timer = date('i:s', $to - $from);
echo("$Timer");
```

Comment: Sure it's possible, but it's likely to be very inaccurate. If you need that kind of precision, you might be better off using websockets. Sending an ajax request to your server every 600ms for every client connected to your server can be very taxing.

Comment: I tested this with 50 users and appeared to work fine. Technically every request is a websocket.

Comment: Well, the idea is with websocket you wouldn't send a request every second, you would just send a note to the javascript instructing it that it needs to stop where it's at and start at 30 seconds again when it gets reset. You could do that with longpolling too i guess.

Comment: @user2924019, no =) [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is separate technology for the _real_ persistent connections.

Comment: Also, your worry of it skipping a second, i guarentee even 600ms wont be enough to make it not skip a second here and there on slow connections. It may even crash the browser on slower connections when the requests take longer than 600ms and build up.

Comment: You should also take into account the time it took for the javascript to get the response. If it took 300ms, you should add 300ms to the time that the server said it was at, if you want to be that precise.

Comment: 600ms does sometimes skip your right. Especially with other requests going on too.

Comment: Not quite, by the JS gets the time, the time would be accurate. the 300ms leading up to that was before the time is returned.

Comment: Arantir - I'm not talking about the function, I am saying that at the end of the day it does the same thing. One terminates, one don't. adding a few MS is nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to tackle this ( correct me if I'm wrong anyone! );

- Fetch the time from the server
- Return [ json ]

  - [server_time]
  - [seconds_left]
  - [miliseconds_left]

Set these values on a function and make sure its called as your contract requires. As soon as this starts hitting < 60 seconds shorten the interval by division of (e.g. the amount of seconds, altough this might not be optimal :-) ).

```
60/60   = 1
50 / 60 = .73
30 / 60 = .5
etc...
```

If the miliseconds are really really crucial I'm afraid you would have to provide some more insight of what it actually is you are trying to accomplish?